# Explicit polyfit with variables

Tags: matlab

I am using polyfit to get the following 4-degree polynomial:

```
   0.5152   -1.0687    0.0269    1.1781   -0.4943
```

I need this polynomial explicitly, i.e., I need to have the variables in it, too. That is I need it as a symbolic expression, e.g.,

```
   f(q) = 0.5152 q^4   -1.0687 q^3    0.0269 q^2    1.1781 q   -0.4943
```

because my function f(q) is the input of another function g(q). Example: I am having function g as:

```
   g(q) = q^2
```

and I need f(q) WITH variable q in it so that I can evaluate g at f symbolically. That is, the result should be a SYMBOLIC function g:

```
   g(f(q)) = ( 0.5152 q^4   -1.0687 q^3    0.0269 q^2    1.1781 q   -0.4943 )^2
```

Any ideas how I can represent f(q) from polyfit such that I can use it as symbolic input in g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`poly2sym`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/poly2sym.html) to transform the vector of coefficients into a symbolic polynomial:

```
>> poly2sym([1 2 3],'x')

ans =

x^2 + 2*x + 3
```